# Как обновить JS без обновления страницы

Tags: javascript, magnific

Если упростить, у меня есть меню, при клике на которой загружаются кнопки, а при клике на одного из них открывается красивый попап JS плагина(magnific popUp). НО, мне приходится обновлять список этих кнопок, добавляя новые без перезагрузки страницы.

Проблема: попапы не открываются на новые кнопки, так как плагин их не прочитал при загрузке страницы(поскольку они были добавлены потом).

Как перезагрузить JS или тот плагин без обновления страницы?

Comment: возможно, [это](https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/issues/778#issuecomment-161270541) может помочь.

Comment: @ya.ymer Спасибо, то что надо